# tinymce token for absolute url

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I use [TinyMCE](https://tinymce.com) to create template for mail letters. In template I should insert absolute url, that at moment I create template is just a string token. Like in tinymce I insert `{{url}}` - this is the link, that later will be replaced with an absolute url.

The problem is that TinyMCE don't allow to insert such token as hyperlink. When I use `insert hyperlink` function on toolbar it insert `http://my-web-site.com/url-where-i-edit-email-template/{{url}}`

I already turn of relative urls and this is work for images

```
tinymce.init({
  //..
  relative_urls : false,
  remove_script_host : false, 
  //..
});
```

What should i do to prevent such behavior for hyperlinks with tokens?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to create a hyperlink as you describe:

[image]

I would imagine this is a configuration issue in how you have TinyMCE setup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, posible solution could be handle url convertion by yourself

TinyMCE allows to do the following

```
function urlConverter(url){
  // do stuff with url ..
  return url;
}

tinymce.init({
  //..
  urlconverter_callback: urlConverter,
  //..
});
```

[Official documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/url-handling/#urlconverter_callback)